# Предложение по цели высказывания

Tags: классификация

Здравствуйте. Возникли разногласия по поводу  цели высказывания предложения "До свидания, журавли". Подскажите, пожалуйста, оно повествовательное или побудительное.

Answer (score 1):

А мне кажется, что это повествовательное предложение, ведь смысл его можно передать следующим образом: "Журавли, мы расстаемся до следующего свидания"

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется побудительное т.к мы обращаемся и говорим до след. свидания, это значит что мы побуждаем к действию, а точнее говорим

Answer (score 0):

Для начала. Побудительные предложения являются повествовательными, поэтому вопрос поставлен не совсем верно, предложение в любом случае повествовательное. 
Является ли оно при этом еще и побудительным - вопрос не простой. Грамматически оно таковым не является, ибо в нем нет специальных форм глагола (повелительного наклонения или форм его заменяющих). Но можно ведь с такой интонацией произнести, что в нем будет явный требование грядущей встречи. Но все-таки в нормальном контексте, да еще и по отношению к журавлям я бы не счел это предложение побудительным.

см. тут: http://russkiyyazik.ru/663/

**//-----**

Насчет побудительных как подвида повествовательных - снимаю.
У Валгиной - деление на повествовательные, побудительные и вопросительные.
http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-130.htm
Остальное - в силе.

Comment: Вот такое слышу первый раз. По цели высказывания предложения бывают повествовательными (цель - сообщить), вопросительными (цель - спросить), побудительными (цель - побудить к действию). Конечно, нет, наверное, в грамматике единой точки зрения ни на одно понятие.Но в традиционной школьной, вузовской грамматике - именно так. А по сути согласна - предложение повествовательное.

Comment: @Ларf, понимаете, я-то считал эту систематику общепризнанной, почему и говорил с абсолютной уверенностью, да и ткнул ссылкой ссылкой в первый попавшийся источник. За что могу только извиниться, ибо по сути спорить не хочется, не тот вопрос.  
Мне важнее другое. В грамматике (как в общем-то и везде) не должно быть "неединой" точки зрения на терминологию. Могут быть разные подходы, формализации и проч. Но о первичных понятиях надо договариваться. Для меня это тем более понятно - как для человека, немоло времени угробившего на неблагодарнейшую работу по созданию грамматических анализаторов.